# Loop through JSON with SwiftyJSON and Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have had a look at the other questions but I cant seem to find one that answers my question.

I have this Json file:

```
[
"posts",
{
  "2015": [
    "post title one"
  ],
  "2016": [
    "post title one",
    "post title two"
  ]
}
]
```

and I have this code in my Swift File:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                for (key, subJson) in json["posts"] {
                    if let year = subJson.string {
                        print(year)
                    }
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I can get the json from the server ok.

On this line:

```
for (key, subJson) in json["posts"] {
```

I get this error:

> immutable value 'key' was never used, consider replaying with '_' or removing it

I tried that, and tried removing it - still nothing displays in the console.

Also, on this line:

```
if let year = subJson.string {
```

I get this error:

> Value of tuple type 'Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') has no member 'string'

What I want to do is this:

Loop through all the years and put them in a uitableview. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
for (_, subJson) in json["posts"] {
    for (year, content) in subJson {
        print(year)
    }
}
```

The first error is just a warning, meaning that you never use the "key" variable and so the compiler suggests to not label it. In my example, you will get a similar warning for `content` since we're not using it: either you use it or you replace it with a `_`.

*Note that I'm inferring your JSON format from your code, because your JSON snippet does look like it's not valid / not the actual one.*

UPDATE:

```
for (_, subJson) in json["posts"] {
    for (year, content) in subJson {
        print(year)
        for (_, title) in content {
            print(title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How should the JSON look? I used PHP to generate it, so maybe I have done it wrong..

Comment: Gunna try your solution now.

Comment: I get immutable value 'content' was never used, consider replaying with '_' or removing it

Comment: Did you read my answer entirely? I was telling you about this, ahah. :D And btw this is a warning, not an actual error.

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed - right. my focus is on! I changed it to the _ but still nothing in the console.

Comment: Then your JSON format is not what you think. Because I've tried my answer in a Playground and it works. // But anyway it doesn't change a thing. :) What you had to grasp is the *idea*, and now you got it: you just have to adapt it to your actual data format, this is something I can't do for you.

Comment: hmm, I have tried viewing the JSON in the browser and that is what is displayed. so the JSON is correct.  I just tried 'for (year, _) in subJson {' instead of  'for (year, _) in subJson["issues"] {' and it worked

Comment: I have no doubts my solution works for you - you just have to adapt to your data, as I said earlier. Here's what I used: [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOx9vxfBTUBDf4hTS_ox9N6rHAUeo6JAiL0).

Comment: If you add that to your answer I will accept so that others know how to do it. - How would I go about looping through all the posts under the year headings?

Comment: P.s - your JSON form is different from mine. Just realized - going to amend my JSON to match yours then re-upload. and try your solution again

Comment: This is because the JSON you show in your question was invalid, I just made the first item as the key for the rest, it seemed logical and was similar to what you were trying in your code.

Comment: yeah, i'm not disputing it, I thank you for correcting my JSON. Literally just getting into programming and trying to build an app. if you don't mind, would you be able to point me in the right direction to then looping through the items under the year headings? again thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. But I don't see anything else... My last update already prints the "post titles" under each year. Or maybe I didn't understand what you're asking now. If you need further help, click on "move this discussion to chat" I *may* have a few minutes for you if needed.

Comment: I am so sorry, I skimmed again - been at this for hours and very tired. Thank you so much for your help. Extremely appreciated.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help. Cheers!